# Where can I pass the properties file in Datastage when using Kafka Connector

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, datastage, keytab

There are some properties that I want to change as, for instance, `security.protocol` from `SASL_PLAINTEXT` to `SASL_SSL`. But the Kafka Connector in Datastage has very limited number of properties (host, use kerberos, principal name, keytab, topic name, consumer group, max poll records, max messages, reset policy timeout and classpath)

While reading [this documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWSR9_11.6.0/com.ibm.swg.im.mdmhs.kafka.export.doc/topics/kafka_security_client.html) the very first thing to do is to pass the JAAS configuration file. But my question is:

1. *Where* should I put this file? In the Datastage or Kafka side?
2. **How** can I point to this file?

This is what I tried:

1. Added a `before-job subroutine` in Datastage and use the following command:

   ```
   export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
   ```
2. Added the `-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf` to the `Kafka Client Classpath` in the Kafka Connector propertis in Datastage

But no matter what I do, everytime that I run the job the parameter `security.protocol` keeps unchanged:

```
Kafka_Connector_2,1: security.protocol = SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

Meaning that it's not reading the properties file.

Have you faced similar problem like these?

Answer (score 1):

The Kafka Connector does have support for SASL SSL
[Kafka Connector Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdidz.png)
This was added in [JR61201](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/JR61201) for 11.5 and is available in 11.7.1.1

If you want to insert a JVM option such as

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf
```

You should be able to leverage the [CC_JVM_OPTIONS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.conn.envvar.ref.doc/topics/r_envvarjav_cc_jvm_options.html) environment variable.